# Unable to require class in index file nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

My config class: ProjectDir/classes/config.js

```
'use strict';
class config{
    getMongo(){
        var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/nodedb', (err, database) => {
            var db;
            if (err) return console.log(err)
            db = database;
            console.log('Connected to mongo');
        });
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

My server.js file(here all routes are defined): ProjectDir/server.js

```
console.log('May Node be with you');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var configClass = require('./classes/config');//this is line 18
var config = new configClass();
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:588:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\node\server.js:18:19)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

With out nodemon:

```
    >node server.js
    May Node be with you
D:\node\classes\config.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ��'
    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
        at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:588:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:
        at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\node\server.js:18:19)
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.8",
    "swagger-tools": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1"
  }
}
```

I am new to node js, i am trying to make my code modular so i create a class called config.js i want to use this class in my index file where all of my routes are written. Please help!!

Comment: `**line 18:**` ?? why this in your code??

Comment: @wrangler I'm assuming he's pointing out that it's line 18 which is where the error is coming from maybe?

Comment: sorry that was a typo, its a comment, as it shows the issue is with line 18

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn: yeahh exactly

Comment: What Node version do you use? (`node -v`)

Comment: Its version 8.7.0

Comment: run without nodemon and print output pliz

Comment: Edited please check, its saying the same thing when running without nodemon

Comment: are u sure u have installed all dependancies `express` `body-parser` `mongodb`  ?

Comment: Please have a look at my package.json edited the question, yeah these are are installed

Comment: If they were not installed so it should give me the errors on the starting line where i am requiring these express body-parser mongodb

Comment: Weird seems ok but i can't tell what wrong! Try to comment line 18 & 19 and run it

Comment: What about this,
May Node be with you
D:\node\classes\config.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ��'

Comment: everything seems ok

Comment: its not working , function getMongo()

Comment: Have you tried adding the extension to the `config` file? Like: `require('./classes/config.js');`

Comment: You mean adding require('./classes/config.js'); at the top of my ProjectDir/classes/config.js ?

Comment: in your server.js

Comment: @AbdulMoiz no, in server.js file at line 18, exactly where the error occurs

Comment: I think i am already doing that in server.js file

Comment: You have this: `require('./classes/config');` and my point is to change it to this: `require('./classes/config.js');`. Note the `.js` at the end of the path

Comment: Yes it tried that too, same result

Comment: Ok, I can see a little space at the beginning of your config.js file. Is it the result of copy-pasting or do you have it in the actual file? If you do, then remove it, so the file starts with `'use strict';`.  Check all your files. I'm saying it because this `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ��'` looks suspicious

Comment: No space there in config.js file.

Comment: This looks not like space, but some bytes that are invalid in the used encoding. Try another editor.

Comment: Yes it seems that its space issue, when i comment that require config line everything works perfectly fine. But unfortunately i am unable to identify it.

Comment: Issue has been resolved, i created a new file and it worked. Then i tried it with the old file again and it gave me same error, its some kind of weird issue with the file. I am on windows. I think it sucks. I even tried renaming that file and replacing all of it content, it gave me same error. When creating a new file its working fine. Its frustrating. It happened to me first time in the career. I even checked the permissions of the file though it doesnot matter alot on windows.

Comment: I figured it out, @Bergi is right, i created a file using power shell(windows 10) using command dir>config.js, thats why it was not working. Sorry guys for inconvenience caused, i am a centos user so i went for power shell straight away. I think I am lacking windows knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in server.js instead (not tested)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var { config } = require('./classes/config');//this is line 18
var config = new config();
```

Comment: Its soo frustrating.. same issue. when i comment line 18 it works perfectly fine

Comment: so try old fashion way instead with prototype. I must admit am new to es6 features

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684177/node-js-es6-classes-with-require

Comment: Yeah i went through this before posting this question.