# Create own class

Tags: node.js, express

created a new project in expressjs. I want to create my own class. So I created a file `MyClass.js` in `/routes/`.

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
    }
}

export default MyClass;
```

And in `/routes/index.js` i added:
`import MyClass from './MyClass';`

And I have an error:

```
import MyClass from './MyClass;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
[...]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js ES6 classes with require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684177/node-js-es6-classes-with-require)

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project is not set up properly to interpret the file that has the error as an ESM module file.  It is, instead, being interpreted as a CommonJS module (where you use `require()`, not `import`) which is the nodejs default.

There are a number of ways to tell nodejs that your file is supposed to be an ESM module.

1. You can give it a file extension of `.mjs`.
2. You can add `"type": "module"` to your package.json file.
3. You can use the `--input-type=module` command line argument when starting node.js if this file is your top level file you're executing.

See nodejs doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system) on this subject.

---

FYI, you could just switch to the CommonJS syntax of using `require()` and `module.exports` instead of `import` and `export`, but I assume what you really want to do is to tell nodejs that you want to use ESM modules so you can use the more modern `import` and `export` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all to export your class you suppose to use `exports` or `module.export`
and to import it you suppose to use `require('')` not `import`.

Those features are only available with .mjs or if you will setup babel though soome es6 features are yet to land in

Comment: The OP clearly intends to use ESM `import` and `export` syntax.  So, while they could convert all their code to CommonJS (using `require()` and `module.exports`), it seems more likely that the desired answer is how to get their file interpreted as an ESM module so they can use the more modern syntax `import` and `export`.